# What is the exact Google Java Format version used by CheckStyle 9.3?

Tags: java, checkstyle, google-java-format

I use Checkstyle **9.3** (because I'm still using JDK 8). I'm wondering what is the exact Google Java Format version used by that Checkstyle version? I'm referring to the following file:

https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-9.3/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

I tried to figure it out. I see a date on the following page stating **"version of 23 May 2018, current as of 07 May 2019"**. Maybe I missed something.

https://checkstyle.org/google_style.html

I think this is either version 1.6 or 1.7.

- https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.googlejavaformat/google-java-format/1.6/index.html
- https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.googlejavaformat/google-java-format/1.7/index.html

This is important to know because I'm using a program to reformat the code automatically, for instance google-java-format. Then I need to know which release to choose here:

https://github.com/google/google-java-format/releases

Thank you

Jonathan

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checkstyle does not use java google formatter project. Checkstyle use its own logic to validate Google Style. There are tons of unclear items in Google style web page, so interpretation of it is different by each tool.

Checkstyle coverage of style guide https://checkstyle.org/google_style.html
There few bugs opened https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22google+style%22